# How can you use Javascript in terminal for w3m?

Tags: javascript, unix, terminal, w3m

I found the text browser w3m which is the best so far in my opinion.
However, it is main problem is Javascript.

I cannot see comments at all in Stackoverflow when I use it.

I am not sure what is the restriction in letting Javascript to be in terminal.

**How can you enable at least some of JavaScript for Terminal** such that comments are visible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javascript requires a Javascript interpreter. If your user-agent doesn't understand a particular kind of scripting, it simply ignores it. To get a minimal level of support, try the **[w3m-js](http://abe.nwr.jp/w3m/w3m-js-en.html)** extension.

Comment: How can you use that code in terminal? Where do I need to put it to run w3m nicely?

Comment: You'll have to download, compile and install the program w3m-js and all the libraries it requires.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20101124213553/http://abe.nwr.jp/w3m/w3m-js-en.html is the most recent non-dead Archive link for http://abe.nwr.jp/w3m/w3m-js.html but even the archive link is not that helpful since links on that page do not really go anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately w3m doesn't support JavaScript at all.

Answer (score -2):

### Try Conkeror

Masi -- I'd recommend taking a look at Conkeror, which is basically Firefox with Emacs keybindings. If you want a keyboard driven UI with Javascript,
it's your best bet:

http://conkeror.org

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/firefox-for-emacs-users/

The frontpage could use a makeover, but once you download and install it you'll wonder why you never tried it before...

(and if you're a vim user, you could try vimperator).

Comment: OP said "letting Javascript to be in terminal" so does Conkeror work under a terminal or does it require an X connection?

Comment: @anonymous2, That is why I believe that Conkeror does not apply to the OP's question. I believe the intent is that the web content needs to be "rendered" into terminal windows such as Linux consoles and dumb terminals that, by design, should not require an X connection.